# implementation of fayad and irani discretization

Tags: entropy, discretization

IS there a java code to implement Fayad and Irani's Entropy based discretization? I have tried reading the file and then calculating the Entropy and Info gain. How to get the bounday points?

I have to implement Fayad and Irani’s discretization algorithm, which is based on entropy and information gain ([Fayad and Irani, 1993]

Answer (score 1):

Yes; here's an implementation:

https://svn.kenai.com/svn/grex~subversion/grex/src/weka/filters/supervised/attribute/Discretize.java